# Stop TinyMCE stripping empty tags in WordPress - yes I have researched already

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce

Like many other people, I have a problem with TinyMCE stripping HTML tags - specifically the empty ones I'm using with Font Awesome.

I have researched and tried solutions and nothing has worked.  I'm not especially strong with PHP, but the problem I'm running into is this: everybody says modifiy the tinyMCE.init function in the tinymce.js file.  However being in the newest version of WP, I don't have that.  What I have class-wp-editor.php, wherein lives this:

```
            /*
         * For people who really REALLY know what they're doing with TinyMCE
         * You can modify $mceInit to add, remove, change elements of the config
         * before tinyMCE.init. Setting "valid_elements", "invalid_elements"
         * and "extended_valid_elements" can be done through this filter. Best
         * is to use the default cleanup by not specifying valid_elements,
         * as TinyMCE checks against the full set of HTML 5.0 elements and attributes.
         */
        if ( $set['teeny'] ) {

            /**
             * Filter the teenyMCE config before init.
             *
             * @since 2.7.0
             *
             * @param array  $mceInit   An array with teenyMCE config.
             * @param string $editor_id Unique editor identifier, e.g. 'content'.
             */
            $mceInit = apply_filters( 'teeny_mce_before_init', $mceInit, $editor_id );
        } else {

            /**
             * Filter the TinyMCE config before init.
             *
             * @since 2.5.0
             *
             * @param array  $mceInit   An array with TinyMCE config.
             * @param string $editor_id Unique editor identifier, e.g. 'content'.
             */
            $mceInit = apply_filters( 'tiny_mce_before_init', $mceInit, $editor_id );
        }
```

Now I know I have to do something with valid_elements, or extended_valid_elements, or verify_html, but I don't know how to do it.  I can see from the comments where to put it, but I don't know which to use or the proper syntax.

I found this fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/j9baab/1 but like I said I don't have that function anywhere in WP.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You really don't want to modify the `class-wp-editor.php` file as each time you update WordPress it will get overwritten.

The easiest way to extend/modify the settings of TinyMCE is to build a simple WordPress Plugin and tie into the hooks WordPress provides to change the editor's settings.

To solve your particular desire to add options to the init you want to look at
the `'tiny_mce_before_init'` hook.  You might do something like this in the plugin:

```
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'add_my_options');

function add_my_options($opt) {   
    // $opt is the existing array of options for TinyMCE 
    // We simply add a new array element where the name is the name
    // of the TinyMCE configuration setting.  The value of the array
    // object is the value to be used in the TinyMCE config.

    $opt['extended_valid_elements'] = '*[*]';
    return $opt;
}
```

Writing a simple WP plugin is not too hard - there are plenty of examples on the web.  For something this simple its really just a single PHP file.  Once you have the plugin built you just install and activate it.  Once activated, your code is run each time TinyMCE is invoked and your options are injected into the init code.

EDIT: Here is the code from the OPs comment (easier to read than how the comments are formatted):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Disable TinyMCE Filters
 * Plugin URI: http://mindspyder.com
 * Description: This plugin disables annoying TinyMCE Filters.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Brandon Snow
 * Author URI: http://mindspyder.com
 * License: GPL2
 */
 add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'add_my_options');

function add_my_options($opt) {   
    // $opt is the existing array of options for TinyMCE 
    // We simply add a new array element where the name is the name
    // of the TinyMCE configuration setting.  The value of the array
    // object is the value to be used in the TinyMCE config.

    $opt['extended_valid_elements'] = '*[*]';
    return $opt;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael - OK I created disable-tinymce-filters.php and uploaded to the plugins folder.  WP recognised it and I activated it.  Nothing changed!  Here are the contents of disable-tinymce-filters.php:

Comment: <?php
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'add_my_options');

function add_my_options($opt) {   
    // $opt is the existing array of options for TinyMCE 
    // We simply add a new array element where the name is the name
    // of the TinyMCE configuration setting.  The value of the array
    // object is the value to be used in the TinyMCE config.

    $opt['extended_valid_elements'] = '*[*]';
    return $opt;
}
?>

Comment: what am I doing wrong?  Will update above so it's easier to read.

Comment: Let's separate this into two issues....  (1) How to configure TinyMCE to do what you want and (2) How to get that configuration into WordPress.  Let's start by building a simple TinyMCE Fiddle that allows you to play with TinyMCE's configuration outside WordPress.  TinyMCE Fiddle is free and will allow you to test various configurations more easily.  Can you create a TinyMCE init in TinyMCE Fiddle that does precisely what you want with your HTML?  Once you make the Fiddle post its URL here so we can see both the init and the HTML that you want it to keep.

Comment: OK Michael - I've tried the fiddle, and I obviously don't know what I'm doing in this regard.  Here is the fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/wwfaab

Here is what I put in:

<a href="http://docwangu.com/product-tag/botswana/">
<div class="flag-wrapper">
<div class="img-thumbnail flag flag-icon-background flag-icon-bw" title="bw" id="bw"></div>
</div>          
Botswana</a>

Here is what I get back:

<div class="flag-wrapper">&nbsp;</div>
<p><a href="http://docwangu.com/product-tag/botswana/">Botswana</a></p>

How do I get this stupid thing to stop changing my code and just leave it be?

Comment: So in most doctypes a DIV cannot be inside an A tag - so TinyMCE is moving this outside the A to make valid HTML.  Can you use a SPAN tag instead?  If I switch your tags to SPAN tags it works.  Try this:  <a href="docwangu.com/product-tag/botswana/">
 <span id="outerspan" class="flag-wrapper"> 
  <span class="img-thumbnail flag flag-icon-background flag-icon-bw" title="bw" id="innerspan"></span> 
 </span> 
 Botswana
</a>